# Inquiry About Robot Framework XPath Regular Expressions

Tags: python, regex, xpath, robotframework

I encountered an issue with XPath while writing automation scripts in Robot Framework, which resulted in data retrieval failures. Below is an HTML example:

```
<div class="content">
  <x-html-3348724a>
    <x-body-3348724a>
```

The serial numbers for x-body and x-html are dynamic and not fixed. I would like to inquire about how to specify data for x-body using regular expressions.

Thank you.

Tried the following methods all failed:

```
xpath=//div[@class="content"]//*[starts-with(x-body)]
xpath=//div[@class="content"]//x-body(.*)
xpath=//div[@class="mail-content"]//^x-body
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the code example that you can use to retrieve data from the dynamic elements in your HTML using XPath and regular expressions in Robot Framework:

```
*** Settings ***
Library           SeleniumLibrary

*** Variables ***
${URL}            Your_URL_here

*** Test Cases ***
Retrieve Dynamic Data Using XPath and Regular Expressions
    Open Browser    ${URL}    chrome
    ${x_body_element}    Get Xpath Count    //div[@class="content"]//*[starts-with(local-name(), 'x-body-')]
    ${x_body_index}    Set Variable    1
    :FOR    ${i}    IN RANGE    1    ${x_body_element}+1
    \    ${x_body_text}    Get Text    (//div[@class="content"]//*[starts-with(local-name(), 'x-body-')])[${i}]
    \    Run Keyword If    '${x_body_text}' != ''    Exit For Loop
    \    Run Keyword If    ${i} == ${x_body_element}    Fail    No matching element found
    \    ${x_body_index}    Set Variable    ${i}
    Log    Found x-body element: ${x_body_text}

    Close Browser
```

Replace `${URL}` with the actual URL you are working with. This script will find dynamic elements with tags that start with "x-body" within the specified class, and retrieve their text content using a loop. If a matching element is found, the loop will exit, and the text content will be logged. If no matching element is found, the script will fail.

Answer (score 0):

If possible try not to use double `//`, because it means `any descendant`, what could effect performance.

I would use this XPath for best performance:

```
//div[@class='content']/*[starts-with(local-name(),'x-html-')]/*[starts-with(local-name(),'x-body-')]
```